# Activity is missing at app start for product flavour

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-manifest

I have a white label android app that has in its flavours only corresponding resource files and manifest.
The app has a single activity.
The main manifest includes the permissions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="29" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.mirrorlink.android.service.ACCESS_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="androidx.car.app.MAP_TEMPLATES" />
<!--    Override Manifest file in flavors -->
</manifest>
```

When I run any flavour configuration on emulator it works fine.
If I try to run it on real device it fails stating that the main activity can not be found.

```
error while executing: am start -n "com.***.***/com.***.***.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER --splashscreen-show-icon
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.***.***/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.***.***/com.***.***.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

The main activity is mentioned in the manifest of flavour like following.

```
...
<activity
            android:name="com.***.***.MainActivity"
            android:label="${appLabel}"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="true"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.mirrorlink.android.app.LAUNCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.mirrorlink.android.app.TERMINATE" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
...
```